# Isomorphism Definition - Error in Hoffman Kunze?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, definition, vector-space-isomorphism

I am Referring to the book Linear Algebra by Hoffman and Kunze $2$e, page  $84$ section $3.3$.

It defines Isomorphism as follows:

> If $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces over a field $\mathbb{F}$, then any one-one $T$ $\in$ $\mathcal{L}(V, W)$ of $V$ onto $W$ is called an **Isomorphism** from $V$ to $W$.

Standing alone, the definition seems correct, but the authors go on to say that:

> if $V$ is Isomorphic to $W$ via an Isomorphism $T$, then $W$ is Isomorphic to $V$ because $T^{-1}$ is an Isomorphism from $W$ to $V$.

I feel this is erroneous, because as per the definition given $T$ is one-one, which doesn't imply the existence of an inverse on its own.

To correct it, either, the term "bijective" must be used instead of one-one, or there should be an additional condition that $~\dim(V) = \dim(W).$

Am I correct in this interpretation? Or am I missing something out?

I tried looking up in the various errata for this book, but couldn't find anything related to this.

Thanks.

Comment: For what it's worth, the general category-theoretic definition of "isomorphism" is a morphism with a two-sided compositional inverse. Here "morphism" just means "linear map".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in the definition of isomorphism given by the author, $T$ is **onto**. So $T$ is bijective by definition.

Additional information:
In general, people use the term *into* when they describe a map from a set $A$ *into* $B$. So **onto** is used for a specific purpose.

Comment: Oh I see, I know onto implies surjection, but I didn't realise that when the author wrote V onto W, he implied surjection, and not a Literary alternative to T maps V to W. Thanks

Comment: To supplement my answer, if people write a general map from a set V to W, they use the term ‘into’ instead of ‘onto’. So ‘onto’ is used specifically.

Answer (score 4):

'onto' means surjective. So one-to-one and onto mean bijective.

Comment: Oh I see, I know onto implies surjection, but I didn't realise that when the author wrote V onto W, he implied surjection, and not a Literary alternative to T maps V to W. Thanks